# Python requests post file inside nested object multipart

Tags: python, json, api, django-rest-framework, python-requests

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
f = open("/path/to/file/screenshot.png", "r")
f2 = open("/path/to/file/screenshot2.png", "r")


data = {
    "type": "1",
    "photos": [
        {"image": f.read()},
        {"image": f2.read()}
    ]
}

print requests.post(url, data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("usr", "pass")).json()
```

The request sends out correctly but the endpoint doesn't get the images that are being sent over.

I tried the same thing with strings instead of images and it worked if I set the content-type manually to application/json

Is it possible to send files inside nested objects like I've displayed ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you forgetting to read the file after you open it ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan Yeah, but the problem is not here.

Comment: Shouldn't you have used the `files` perameter?

Comment: @t.m.adam possibly. If so I don't know how

Comment: Example: `files={"image":f}` More info: [python-requests: post-a-multipart-encoded-file](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: @t.m.adam yes, but how can I post inside nested element ? files={"photos": [{"image": f}]} gives me an error: too many values to unpack

Comment: Please provide full traceback, DRF version and the request header that get sent. Also remember to send request with multipart content type.